# iOS app looks different on device vs. simulator/other identical device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I'm not really sure if there's a better way to phrase this, but the same build of our iOS app (iOS 9) renders differently on my device and my colleague's identical device (both are iPhone 6s Plus, no special custom settings). It looks "right" on mine (matches the simulator), but on hers, there are layout differences that we can't figure out.

Here's what it looks like when rendered as expected (this is what it looks like in simulator as well):

Rendering as expected
[image: rendering as expected]

Here's what it looks like on her device -- we can't figure this out, but it looks like the circles with the icons and the mini paragraph of text aren't following the layout constraints.

We can't figure this one out:
[image: we can't figure this one out]

Any thoughts? We'd hate to have this be an issue for users, but I'm unable to replicate it on my device or in sim.

Comment: Have you try deleting the app from both devices and reinstalling them? Are you using auto layout and storyboards?

Comment: Yep. Have definitely deleted and reinstalled. We're using autolayout, and have 0 problems on simulator, other devices, etc -- this is the only one rendering like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like on first device (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewk8R.png) display is zoomed and on second one (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ch7y4.png) display has standard view. To change it go to Settings > Display&Brightness > View and choose Standard or Zoomed option.

Comment: Aah! Thank you; that's it. Will have to look into what we might be able to do in case users have their view set differently -- I think the left-aligned appearance on those circles was throwing us off.